# MySQL: Match entry in table2 to those in table1 using an id, then insert matches as new column into table2

Tags: mysql, sql, database, merge

Suppose I have two datasets of students. I want to match students in one dataset to another. The match criteria is whether the first 4 letters of the first name, last 4 letters of last name, and the first 4 letters of the first word in the high school name match. If these are all true, we assume that the students are the same.

I am able to accomplish this using

```
SELECT t1.`Full Name`, t1.`uid_hist`, t2.`fullname`, t2.`hsname`, t1.`High School`
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
on SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(t2.fullname), '^[a-z]*?[^a-z]'), 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(t1.`Full Name`), '^[a-z]*?[^A-z]'), 1, 4)
and SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(t2.fullname), '[^a-z][a-z]*?$'), -4) = SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(t1.`Full Name`), '[^a-z][a-z]*?$'), -4)
and SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(t2.hsname), '^[a-z]*?[^a-z]'), 1, 4) = SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(t1.`High School`), '^[a-z]*?[^a-z]'), 1, 4)
```

This is pretty slow, so I am also curious if there is a better way, but it appears to work as intended.

Now, my question is, how do I go about inserting the matched 'uid's from table 1 as a new column in table2? That is, if there is a student who was matched to a student in table1, then the unique identifier for that student in table1 will be in the column 'match'. For students that are not matched, 'match' will simply be null.

If a row in table2 is matched to more than one student in table1, let's say we repeat the row in table2, except with different values for 'match'.

Is there any straightforward way to accomplish this? I am very new to MySQL and not sure how  to proceed

Comment: How do you determine the last name from first name in FULLNAME column?

Comment: oh right. i misunderstood the question. Gordon Linoff has the answer.

Comment: `[A-z]` should be `[a-z]`.

Comment: oh yes, good catch - will fix that!

Comment: @jackson5 . . . Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: With a surname of e.g. `Li`, what would you expect the `lastname` portion of the match to look like?

Comment: I would expect it to be a full match in that case,(so “li”) - also yes I will try and add sample data and output soon!

Comment: It turns out I went to school with several people who were all in fact exactly the same person.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need regular expressions for this:

```
SELECT t1.`Full Name`, t1.`uid_hist`, t2.`fullname`, t2.`hsname`, t1.`High School`
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON LEFT(t2.fullname, 4) = LEFT(LOWER(t1.`Full Name`) AND
        RIGHT(t2.fullname, 4) = RIGHT(LOWER(t1.`Full Name`) AND
        LEFT(t2.`High School`, 4) = LEFT(LOWER(t1.`High School`)
```

Comment: The regexp appears to be intended to split it into first name and last name.

Comment: `[^A-z]` is intended to make the regexp stop at the delimiter between the names. Of course, it shoiuld be `[^a-z]`.

Comment: The only issue here is that, if some students have last named that are only 2/3 letters long, then we would just want the last name to match, without also grabbing a bit of the first name